# how do i work with ListView.Item.CurrentItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, icollectionview

this is my xaml:

```
    <ListView Name="myListView" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=IndexPage, Path=SeriesCollection}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectionChanged="handleSelected">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel >
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel>
            </WrapPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>            
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel >
                <Image Width="214" Height="317" Source="{Binding Image}"/>
                <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

and this is my code behind

```
    public void handleSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        object currentSerie = myListView.Items.CurrentItem;
        Console.WriteLine(currentSerie.GetType());
        Console.WriteLine(currentSerie.ToString());
    }
```

how do i work with currentSerie? how do i access the data which is stored in each Item? i cant access properties and i cant convert it to anything else then object.

also interesting, the output of the code is not "object" but "Series" so ToString() and GetType() gets the type right.

thx for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply cast currentSerie to type Series.

```
Series currentSerie = (Series)myListView.Items.CurrentItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are casting to object so you only get the properties of object.  Cast is to a the real custom class and you will get the properties of that class.  myClass currentSer =

Comment: i am not casting at all (as far as i know). if a change object currentSerie to Serie currentSerie (my custom class) i get "Compiler Error CS0266" -> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'type1' to 'type2'.An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: Yes you are casting   "object currentSerie" is a cast.  Casting to the actual class is my answer and the answer you accepted.

Comment: how is "object currentSerie" a cast? and if it is, why i have to cast Items.CurrentItem to myClass if it is not from type object?

Comment: Dude I am just trying to help. In my answer I explain why you have to cast to the specific class. I used myClass as an example for you to substitute the real name of your class.  From the problem it was not clear that Series was the name of you class.

Comment: i am realy greatful for your help and i realy just want to understand what you are trying to teach me. 

so far you told me 
object x = myListView.Items.CurrentItem; is a cast to object. And that is what i do not understand. 

but thats not your fault (- ; thanks for your time.

Comment: Look at the right hand side myListView.Items.CurrentItem is a ListViewItem that is implicitly cast to object in the absense of a specific cast.   object x is a declaration

Answer (score 0):

How about [casting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx) it?

```
Series series = (Series)myListView.Items.CurrentItem;
```